# How to test Ruby class with default parameters using RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a class called Grid:

```
class Grid

  attr_reader :rows, :columns

  def initialize(rows=20, columns=20)

    @rows = rows
    @columns = columns
  end
end
```

I want to test that the rows and columns fields return 20 by default and return whatever integer is supplied otherwise. I don't know the best way to do this.

I "solved" this by creating two Grid instances. One has supplied values for rows and columns. The other one does not have supplied values and thus uses the default values of 20.

```
require_relative 'spec_helper.rb'

describe Grid do

  let(:grid) {Grid.new(15, 15)}
  let(:gridNoParameters) {Grid.new()}

  subject { grid }

  describe "#rows" do

    its(:rows) { should eq(15) }

    context "when parameter not supplied" do
      subject { gridNoParameters }

      its(:rows) { should eq(20) }
    end
  end

  describe "#columns" do
    its(:columns) { should eq(15) }

    context "when parameter not supplied" do

    subject { gridNoParameters }

    its(:columns) { should eq(20) }
  end
end
```

Is this the best way to test? Any help is appreciated as I am pretty new to Rspec and test driven development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would lay out the spec like this:

```
describe Grid do
  context "#initialize" do
    context "with parameters" do
      let(:grid) { Grid.new(15, 15) }

      it "should use specified values" do
        expect(grid.rows).to eq 15
        expect(grid.columns).to eq 15
      end
    end

    context "without parameters" do
      let(:grid) { Grid.new }

      it "should use defaults" do
        expect(grid.rows).to eq 15
        expect(grid.columns).to eq 15
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Take a look at [BetterSpecs](http://betterspecs.org) for ideas how to organize specs, and to use expect notation, etc. I'm not a huge fan of using `subject` here, but it's up to you, as it is personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is fine.

- You're testing the default
- You're testing the non-default

This particular test strikes me as a bit defensive/paranoid, but if it's critical that a test fails if/when someone accidentally changes or removes the default values, then I guess this test is fine.

Testing constructors is always a little weird to me, if all the constructor does is copy the input parameters to the instance variables. It borders on testing that the `=` operator in Ruby actually works, which is a bit silly. It also borders on what I call, "testing against typos," where the test will only fail if a developer makes a blindingly obvious mistake or removes a default from a method without thinking it through. The thing is, I don't believe that any amount of testing can successfully protect against sloppiness.

There are more complex situations where I might be this careful, but the class you're presenting as an example here is so simple and so straightforward that I don't think it needs anything more than this, personally.